# Using AppleScript to "Put Back" Trash items

Tags: applescript

I've been trying to write a script to "Put Back" files in the trash. The code as it stands now is as follows:

```
property file_list : {}
property cur_file : ""

# Using system events because we need to use mouse clicks
# First hide everything but the Finder
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        click menu item "Hide Others" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Finder" of menu bar 1
    end tell

    # The "Put Back" menu item is only available when the special Dock-launched Trash
    # window is active. It's not available when the Trash is accessed from a
    # regular Finder window (i.e. Go To Folder..., etc.)
    tell process "Dock"
        click UI element "Trash" of list 1
    end tell

    get the POSIX path of every disk item of trash
    # discard the first item, which is (should be?) ".DS_Store"
    set file_list to items 2 thru -1 of result

    repeat until length of file_list is 0
        set cur_file to first item of file_list
        tell process "Finder"
            # the next line is where the error occurs
            select (file where path is cur_file) # this is where the error occurs
            # error "Can't get file whose path = "/Full/path/to/file" number -1728
            click menu item "Put Back" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

As noted in the script comments, the Trash window must be foremost, and the script fails when trying to find something in that window. I've also tried

```
get the name of every disk item of trash
```

with

```
click file where name is cur_file
```

but get basically the same results - "Can't get file whose name = "nameOfFile" number -1728

I'm going to keep plugging away at this but could use some help; I'm not that familiar with AppleScript.

[edit]
So here's what I finally came up with:

```
property file_list : {}
property cur_file : ""
property loop_counter : 0

# Using system events because we need to use mouse clicks
# First hide everything but the Finder
tell application "Finder" to close every window
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Finder"
    click menu item "Hide Others" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Finder" of menu bar 1
end tell
# Get all files in Trash except for the first, which is probably ".DS_Store"
set file_list to items 2 thru -1 of (get the POSIX path of every file of trash)

repeat until loop_counter is equal to length of file_list
    set loop_counter to loop_counter + 1

    # Pause for a few seconds every so often to let the computer chill out.
    # Can be changed if necessary.
    if (loop_counter mod 200) = 0 then delay 20

    # Try to get file from list of names
    try
        set cur_file to item loop_counter of file_list
    end try

    # Make the Trash window active. Must be done with mouse click on
    # Dock icon in order to make the "Put Back" menu item available.
    tell process "Dock" to click UI element "Trash" of list 1

    # Select the next item to put back
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        try
            set target of window "Trash" to (POSIX file cur_file)
        end try
    end tell

    # Delay to allow UI to catch up with script.
    delay 0.25

    # Try to put back the selected item. For some reason doesn't always work.
    try
        tell process "Finder" to click menu item "Put Back" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end try

    # Delay to allow UI to catch up with script.
    delay 0.25

    tell application "Finder" to close every window
end repeat
end tell
```

Isn't pretty, but it works. Try blocks are where the script would sometimes get ahead of the UI and fail. With them, the script will ignore that file and move on to the next. The   0.25 second delays seem to help prevent that, though.

I'd be interested in a solution that uses the command line instead, because the way this runs it takes over the UI until it finishes or is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your approach is far too complicated... I tried something short and clean in Applescript and it works like a charm:

```
-- preparing an empty list for later use
set selectedFiles to {}

-- asking the Finder for files in trash
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    -- check if the trash contains files
    if (count of (trash's files)) > 0 then
        -- open Finder's trash window
        open trash
        -- select all files in Finder's trash window
        set selectedFiles to (select files of front window)
    end if
end tell

-- if files are selected, press backspace and command together
if (count of selectedFiles) > 0 then
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            -- Press backspace using Command down
            key code 51 using command down
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

Enjoy, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thanks for the response. The script was written for someone who accidentally Trashed everything in their Pictures folder - over 16,000 files. I did try the "key code 51 using command down" approach while testing and ended up with my Pictures folder in the trash because (I think) that the script got ahead of the UI. I put in the delay commands and try blocks to help mitigate that. I'll fiddle with the script when I get a chance and try to eliminate using System Events, and if "open trash" works I'll try that and see if it lowers the UI overhead.

Comment: One question: Why do you want to do it with a script? It sounds like you only need it once. 16000 files are a lot but it should work manually, slowly but it should.

Comment: This type of situation is perfect for a script - a repetitive task that needs to be done thousands of times. Also, when I searched for a solution to this particular issue I could find none; now a couple different approaches are available. Seems to me this is exactly what StackExchange is for.

Comment: Ok, you want to do this 16000 times for each file. I thought you can do it once with 16000 files. The first is definitely something to script the second is not. In my solution I open the trash once and select all files, that's why I thought manually or scripted should be same ;-) And now I think I know where your problem is: Using `key code 51 using command down` opens the windows of the laid back files' locations. 
Did you have success using `open trash` to get the trash window focused?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try "open trash" yet; I'm on the road and won't really have the time until this week-end. Another problem that the script tries to solve is that "Put Back" only works for multiple files if they're from the same location. The pics themselves, not the "Pictures" folders, were deleted, which means lots of sub-folders. I also want to look at ".DS_Store", which stores the "Put Back" info. Might be able to use it and a shell script, which I think would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. macOS High Sierra

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Finder"
    repeat 100 times
        tell application "Finder" to open trash
        tell application "Finder" to activate
        key code 126
        key down command
        key code 51
        key up command
        delay 0.2 -- adjust delay as needed
    end repeat
end tell
end tell
tell application "Finder" to close every window
```

Comment: @do01 Sometimes it can be wise to adjust the delay. Some older computers needs more time between each transfer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on macOS Catalina

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set filesInTrash to (files of trash)
    repeat with f in filesInTrash
        select f
        tell application "System Events" to key code 51 using {command down}
        -- Workaround: Give Finder time to show file on new location
        select f
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the mix (and because I dislike using the Finder any more than absolutely necessary):

```
tell application "System Events"
    set trash_folder to open trash
    set trash_items to disk items of trash_folder
    repeat with this_item in trash_items
        tell application "Finder" to select (this_item as alias)
        tell process "Finder"
            tell first menu bar's menu "File"'s menu item "Put Back"
                click
            end tell
            tell window 1 to cancel
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

I have no idea why 'Tell window 1 to cancel' successfully sends the newly opened window to the background, but it seems to work...